# Create a delay to close JFrame after a JButton is clicked

Tags: java, database, swing, oop, jframe

I'm currently working on a Database program, but have run into an issue. I am trying to create a JFrame that prompts a user for what to do, then when they click a button, a method in another class is called (db.createDB() or db.openDB()). I'm not sure exactly how to add a timer to dispose of the frame ONLY after one of the buttons has been clicked.

Thanks in advance!
~Jared

Here is my code:

````
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

/**
 *
 * @author Jared Rathbun
 */
public class Driver {

    private Database db;
    private IDCount count;

    Driver() {
        // Initialize the DB and IDCounter.
        db = new Database();
        count = new IDCount();

        try {
            // Set the look and feel to the system default.
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                    "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException
                | InstantiationException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            System.out.println("Look and Feel not set");
        }

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Select an Option");

        JLabel label = new JLabel("What would you like to do?");
        label.setBounds(8,10,390,50);

        JButton newDBButton = new JButton("Create a New Database");
        newDBButton.setBounds(30,75,150,45);

        JButton openDBButton = new JButton("Open a Database");
        openDBButton.setBounds(210,75,150,45);

        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        f.add(newDBButton);
        f.add(openDBButton);
        f.add(label);

        f.setSize(400,200);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Add actionListeners for both buttons.
        newDBButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                db.createDB();
            }            
        });

        openDBButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               db.openDB();
           }
        });    

        // NEEDS TO CLOSE A FEW SECONDS AFTER ONE OF THE BUTTONS IS CLICKED
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Driver();
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a call to f.dispose() inside each button listener, right after calling dc.createDB() and/or db.openDB(). That way, dc.createDB and db.openDB code will execute and the frame f will be closed right afterwards. If you still want to wait some seconds, try adding the line *TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);* before calling f.dispose();

```
    // Add actionListeners for both buttons.
    newDBButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            db.createDB();
            f.dispose()
        }            
    });

    openDBButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           db.openDB();
           try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);  // wait 3 seconds
           } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
           f.dispose();
       }
    });
```

Hope it helps.

P.S. Also, you might want to check if using a JDialog for this purpose, instead of JFrame, would be better.

Comment: This really helped! Thank you! Could you elaborate more on why using a JDialog might be better than using a JFrame?

Comment: A JDialog would present the user a frame on top of everything else, in a way that the user won't be able to interact with the rest of the program until that frame is "resolved". In your case, it would mean the user is shown the frame to either create or open a database, and only when the user has selected either of the options the program will continue its flow. It can also return some value.